# Spring Roo. Deleting .aj archives without generating new ones

Tags: eclipse, shell, spring-roo

I have installed the Roo Shell 2.0.0.RELEASE in my eclipse. I have never worked with Roo, but, as I understood, it will regenerate the .aj files of my imported roo project when I modify something in them.

However, when you open the projects, it just delete the .aj with commands like this:

```
roo> Deleted SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\bbva\front\oorg\cirbe\cirbedaos\dto\vinculaciones\DetalleVinculacionesDaoOutDto_Roo_JavaBean.aj - not required for governor com.bbva.front.oorg.cirbe.cirbedaos.dto.vinculaciones.DetalleVinculacionesDaoOutDto
```

I don't know if I should write or configure something else, since most manuals I see only say that the Shell should generate these files automatically. Any idea about what im missing?

Indicate that I think the project used to work with shell 1.1.5 (i imported an existing project), but I was unable to open it, so I used 2.0.0. It is assumed that Roo has also updated this in the POM files:

```
Updated ROOT\pom.xml [updated property 'roo.version' to '2.0.0.RELEASE'; updated property 'roo.version' to '2.0.0.RELEASE']
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Roo uses the annotations included in your `.java` files to generate the `.aj` files. Each version of Spring Roo could provide/deprecate different annotations. Spring Roo 2.x is a major update, and it does not support some of the annotations of Spring Roo 1.x

https://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/current/reference/html/#no-backward-compatibility

As you said, the project was created with the 1.x version of Spring Roo, so the generated code included annotations that are not supported by the 2.x version of Spring Roo. That is the reason because your .aj files are being removed with the message `not required for governor`.

Also, I guess that a warning message appeared to you in the Spring Roo shell before to open the project.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi. First of all, thanks for the fast reply. Reading that, i suppose that, if i change the old commands (like @RooJavaBean or @RooToString) for new ones, the shell should work?

Comment: Hi. The project layout libraries, classes,... are not compatible between both versions. I's not just matter of change the annotations. There is no automatic way to move a 1.x project to 2.x. I'm sorry.